# Can mmap() guarantee the data integrity on crash, if I store data chunks in 1/n of Linux PAGE_SIZE?or disk block size?

Tags: linux, io, mmap, persistent, data-integrity

I need to design a system with data persistent and fast reload, which is implemented with `mmap()`. But systems using `mmap()` for persistence often lost data integrity on system crash, like single node MongoDB.

What I have is a very flat data structure to store: data are chunked into 1024 sized blocks, no dependency between blocks. Blocks are randomly and heavily accessed and updated during the server uptime.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `msync` to flush mmapped data to disk.

See http://linux.die.net/man/2/msync.

Comment: Have used `mmap` many times, but never where there was persistence concerns so I had not dabbled with `msync`. Learning has occurred. Thanks.